# Code to execute FormResize event

Tags: delphi

I have tried a number of ways to force the FormResize event to execute without sucess including SetWindowPos.  The following code works very well when the form is resized with the mouse, but I also need to call this manually with code.  I do not want the form to change in any way however.

```
procedure TFormMain.FormResize( Sender: TObject );
begin
  dxDockPanelFolders1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
  dxDockPanelFiles1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
  dxDockPanelPreview1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
end;
```

I have not see anyway to accomplish this while searching the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the event to fire, or is it enough if only the event handler is executed? If it is, simply do

```
FormResize(Self);
```

If you really need the event to fire, just do

```
Resize;
```

Comment: Darn, 28 seconds... My internet provider is slow today

Comment: @Marjan If you can't be first, be better!

Comment: @David, yes, that's a good idea. Except after finding out Andreas submitted his answer 28 seconds before my almost identical one (he edited afterwards), I got beaten to the better answer by you as well. :-) Guess it just isn't my day... :-)

Comment: Thank-you all.  Actually I just found out I can use the dxDockSite1UpdateResizeZones event to reposition the panels, but it is good to know how to execute the FormResize event as well.  And thanks to David Heffernan for his suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I would use some indirection:

```
procedure TFormMain.UpdateDockPanelLayout;
begin
  dxDockPanelFolders1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
  dxDockPanelFiles1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
  dxDockPanelPreview1.Height := dxVertContainerDockSite1.Height div 3;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateDockPanelLayout;
end;
```

Now you can call `UpdateDockPanelLayout` directly from anywhere in your code.

I realise that you can call `FormResize` and pass a `Sender` but that solution somehow makes me feel dirty.  Doing it as suggested above also allows you to name the method more specifically and not be so tightly coupled with the UI events that drive it.

Comment: +1. Invoking an event handler as a method DIRECTLY as shown in someone else's answer, IS dirty,  the event handler should invoke a well-named function, which can also be separately invoked.

Comment: I deleted my similar answer for you being the first.

Answer (score -1):

Uh, just call

```
FormResize(nil);
```

when you need to adjust the controls?